# After adding a profile in contact list It does not renders on it... Have to refresh the page due to which contact data are sent two times

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

There are three files one is index.js from which server is running and other two are ejs files which are needed to be rendered. I have tried to render it and redirect it many times but no effect is seen. I think I need ajax to handle this situation but I am new to this. Please help me out.
//index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const port = '8000';
const db = require('./config/mongoose');
const Contact = require('./models/contact')
const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.use(express.urlencoded());

var post = [
    {
        name:"karan chugh",
        phone:"8572004974"
    }
]
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    Contact.find({}, function(err, contacts) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('err');
        }
        res.render('home1',
        {
            persons_list : contacts 
        });
    })
    // return res.render('home1', 
    // {
    //     title : "Kidnapped Persons",
    //     persons_list : post
    // });
})
app.post('/create-contact/', function(req, res) {
    // post.push({
    //     name:req.body.name,
    //     phone: req.body.phone
    // });
    Contact.create({
        name : req.body.name,
        phone: req.body.phone
    }, function(err, newContact) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('error');
            return;
        }
        console.log('*****' , newContact);
    })
    Contact.find({}, function(err, contacts) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('err');
        }
        res.render('home1',
        {
            persons_list : contacts 
        });
    })

    
});
// app.get('/create-contact/' , function(req, res) {
//     res.render('home1');
// })
app.get('/profile' , function(req,res) {
    res.render('profile');
})
app.get('/delete-contact', function(req, res) {
    // getting the id
    let id = req.query.id;

    Contact.findByIdAndDelete(id, function(err , contacts) {
        if(err) {
            console.log('error');
            return;
        }
        return res.render('home1', {
            persons_list : contacts
        }
        );
        
    })
})
app.listen(port, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log('error');
    }
    console.log('server is running on ', port);
});
```

//home page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="mind.js"></script>
  <style>
    /* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
    .topnav {
      background-color: lightblue;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    /* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
    .topnav a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
    }

    /* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
    .active {
      background-color: #4CAF50;
      color: white;
    }

    /* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
    .topnav .icon {
      display: none;
    }

    /* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */
    .dropdown {
      float: left;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    /* Style the dropdown button to fit inside the topnav */
    .dropdown .dropbtn {
      font-size: 17px;
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      color: white;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      background-color: inherit;
      font-family: inherit;
      margin: 0;
    }

    /* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    /* Style the links inside the dropdown */
    .dropdown-content a {
      float: none;
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }

    /* Add a dark background on topnav links and the dropdown button on hover */
    .topnav a:hover,
    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background-color: #555;
      color: white;
    }

    /* Add a grey background to dropdown links on hover */
    .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: #ddd;
      color: black;
    }

    /* Show the dropdown menu when the user moves the mouse over the dropdown button */
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }

    /* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

      .topnav a:not(:first-child),
      .dropdown .dropbtn {
        display: none;
      }

      .topnav a.icon {
        float: right;
        display: block;
      }
    }

    /* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .topnav.responsive {
        position: relative;
      }

      .topnav.responsive a.icon {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
      }

      .topnav.responsive a {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
      }

      .topnav.responsive .dropdown {
        float: none;
      }

      .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {
        position: relative;
      }

      .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: left;
      }
    }

    .pbox {
      border: 4px chocolate dotted;
      /* isplay: flex; */
    }

    center {
      width: 60%;
    }

    .main {
      display: flex;
    }
    right {
      border: 2px dotted red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <navbar>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
      <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>

      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Services
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="/profile">Add a profile</a>
          <a href="#"></a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="#news">About us</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <a href="#about">Emergency</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </div>
  </navbar>
  <section class="main">
    <aside>
      <div id="sidebar">
        Search
        <input id="search">
      </div>
    </aside>
    <center>
      <div>
          <ul>
              <% for(let i of persons_list) { %>
                <li>
                  <div class="details">
                    <p><%= i.name%></p>
                    <p><%= i.phone %></p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <a href="/delete-contact/?id=<%= i._id %>">
                        <i class="fas fa-window-close">delete</i>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                </li>

            <%} %> 
          </ul>
          
      </div>
      


    </center>
    <right>
      <span>States</span>
      <br>
      <div class="statcheck">
        <input type="checkbox" checked> India
      </div>
      <div class="statcheck">
        <input type="checkbox"> Punjab
      </div>
      <div class="statcheck">
        <input type="checkbox"> Himachal Pradesh
      </div>
      <div class="statcheck">
        <input type="checkbox"> Haryana
      </div>
      <div class="statcheck">
        <input type="checkbox"> Maharashtra
      </div>
      <div class="statcheck">
        <input type="checkbox"> Rajasthan
      </div>
    </right>
  </section>


</body>

</html>
```

// contact form page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/create-contact" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter name">
        <input type="number" name="phone" placeholder="enter Phone">
        <button type="submit">Add contact</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and last is database file

```
const { MongoServerSelectionError } = require('mongodb');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const conatactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : {
        type :String,
        required:true
    },
    phone : {
        type:String,
        required: true
    }
});
const Contact = mongoose.model('Contact' , contactSchema);
module.exports = Contact;
```

Answer (score 0):

use javascript predefine function setTimeout that will refresh your page after 1 (you can also change the time for refresh )

```
<% setTimeout(()=>{ for(let i of persons_list) { %>
                <li>
                  <div class="details">
                    <p><%= i.name%></p>
                    <p><%= i.phone %></p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <a href="/delete-contact/?id=<%= i._id %>">
                        <i class="fas fa-window-close">delete</i>
                      </a>
                    </div>
                </li>

            <%} }, 1000%>
```

this is one of the methods to update the data on your page